# Add a native Plugin to Cordova 2.9.0 xcode

Tags: xcode, plugins, cordova

Aim is to have a "View PDF" button which allows the user to view the PDF on an iPad.

Here is the [plugin](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/08/15/open-with-in-ios-phonegap-apps/) I want to add to Cordova (Phonegap).

[This](https://github.com/triceam/phonegap-plugins/commit/83f33d4655751290dd663301a02e50459f06b13f) is the code on GitHub.

So far I have updated my html file to run the scripts and same function on button click (All this is in the body tag like his example):

```
<button id="externalPdf" onclick="app.openExternalDoc();">Open pdf</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/ExternalFileUtil.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("initialize app");
    app.initialize();
</script>
```

I have copied the Index.js and ExternalFileUtil.js into the project.

I have linked the 2 Objective-C file to the plugin folder (Not sure if this is correct)

And I have edited the config.xml file to run the plugin:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="ExternalFileUtil" value="CDVExternalFileUtil"/>
</plugins>
```

It still doesn't seem to work though, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin needs updating to use the [new plugin signature](https://github.com/shazron/phonegap-questions/issues/13) in order to use it with the most recent versions of Phonegap. The JS is OK, but the Objective-C needs updating.

For example, change:

```
- (void) openWith:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
```

to

```
- (void) openWith:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
```

Comment: if i do that change, it brings up 3 more errors saying undeclared arguments just below

Comment: You need to change more than just that line - that was just an example. The plugin needs a full rework. You'll need to change the signature in both the .h and .m files. Another change is how arguments are passed to the plugin, for example `NSString *path = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];` must change to `NSString *path = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: I managed to get it running without the changes you have mentioned..

It outputs from theCDVExternalFileUtil.m when you un comment the bottom 2 NSLog files:

Path to file: /var/mobile/applications.53.....08/Documents/doc.PDF
File exists: 0
is deletable at path: 1

but it doesn't run like his preview linked above.

All the other code in the program seems to run fine without any errors...