# NSArray and new plugin signature with Phonegap 2.9

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm working with a Phonegap 2.9.0 project with Xcode 4.6,
I'm in trouble with a [ExternalFileUtil plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ExternalFileUtil).

It's all installed, but it doesn't work.

As these [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592050/add-a-native-plugin-to-cordova-2-9-0-xcode) says, I have recoded the plugin with the new plugin signature,

But I have an error message, because of these code,

```
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult;
NSString* callbackID = [command.arguments pop];
[callbackID retain];
```

Error message:

```
> * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
> removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object' *
> First throw call stack: (0x1c5012 0x2a55e7e 0x1c4deb 0x245c4f 0x7f910
> 0x7f98d 0x2e38a 0x93deb 0x9353b 0x930ad 0x93236 0x93163 0x2a696b0
> 0x1675765 0x148f3f 0x14896f 0x16b734 0x16af44 0x16ae1b 0x38867e3
> 0x3886668 0x400ffc 0x2b7c 0x2ad5) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called
> throwing an exception (lldb)
```

There is an alert message

> 'NSArray may not respond to 'pop''

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Thanks,
best regards,

Answer (score 0):

question closed.

Old plugin signature works properly,
the problem was that IOS simulator didn't work with that plugin and you have to test it on real devecie.

That's all!

Best regards